# How to map a nested entities which both are attached to other single Entity in EF Core 3

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core.
Need to store Notes in Folder and sub Folder. So Entities are as

```
public class Category {
    public Category() {
        Childrens = new List<Folder>();
    }       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    
    public List<Folder> Childrens { get; set; }
}

public class Folder {
    public Folder() {
        Notes = new List<Note>();
        Children = new List<SubFolder>();
    }       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public List<SubFolder> Children { get; set; }
}

public class SubFolder {
    public SubFolder() {
        Notes = new List<Note>();            
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
    public DateTime Reminder { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int ContainerId { get; set;} //Could be folder/subFolder id      
}
```

A "Catergory" Entity have many "Folder"/s (say parent folders), each folder itself can have further "SubFolder" (say child folder) and no more further levels of sub-folder.
So relation is as
Category => Folder/s (parent folders)=> Folder/s. (child folders). that's it.

How to link a "Note" entity, which could be in a Parent-Folder or in any Child Folder?
[image]

Question:- As Folder & SubFolder are almost the same entities (except no more folders under SubFolder). For simplicity, let considering them two separate entities, so EFcore mapped to two DB tables. right. As a Note entity could be in a Folder or SubFolder. But mapped using EFcore 3.1, Note Db table have two foreign keys, one for Folder and other for SubFolder. Instead of a single foreign key for containing folder key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your database design is wrong. all (category, folder, and subfolder) are the same and you should not separate them. for resolving your problem you should use self-referencing and merge (category, folder, and subfolder) to one specific model and If one folder has a parent just set a `parentId`. follow the below codes:

**Folder** Model:

```
 public class Folder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("ParentFolder")]
        public int? ParentFolderId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    }
```

And you **Note** model is like that:

```
public class Note
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
        public DateTime Reminder { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Folder")]
        public int FolderId { get; set; }
        public Folder Folder { get; set; }
    }
```

Feel free to ask questions.
good luck.